# Node.js/Electron/React: msnodesqlv8 installation warns Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, electron, yarnpkg

I am trying to make a simple electron app built on the electron react boilerplate that queries a local instance of a Microsoft SQL server that I have. Since I want to use Windows Authentication it seems that I have to use the msnodesqlv8 package, but on install it throws a series of warnings that then lead to errors and crashes on startup.

My system environment is electron react boilerplate (which includes webpack) installed on 64-bit Windows 10, with a local running instance of a MS SQL Server 2017. I do my package management through yarn, but npm install yields the same issues. Cmd is being run as an administrator. My process versions are as follows:

`chrome: "78.0.3904.130"
 electron: "7.1.4"
 node: "12.8.1"
 v8: "7.8.279.23-electron.0"`

The exact log on yarn is:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/bootstrap.js 37:23-38
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/sql.js
 @ dll renderer

WARNING in ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/bootstrap.js 57:25-40
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/sql.js
 @ dll renderer
```

it seems to be an error in the included bootstrap library, but I have not found any way to stop it or fix it. If anyone knows how to make this driver work (or any MSSQL Windows authentication alternatives to msnodesqlv8), I would appreciate the help.

## Edit

I found a tentative workaround thanks to [TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/pull/131](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/pull/131), using the following steps.

1. install [node-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/node-loader)

`npm install node-loader --save-dev` or `yarn add node-loader`

add the following rule to your `webpack.config.js` (or `webpack.config.base.js`, if using `electron-react-boilerplate`)

```js
  {
    test: /\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader'
  }
```

2. install [node-sql-server-v8/pull/131](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/pull/131)

If you already have the `mssqlv8` package installed, remove it by running `npm uninstall mssqlv8` or `yarn remove mssqlv8`. Then reinstall the specific pull request with `npm` or `yarn`:

`npm install --save-dev TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8#pull/131/head`

`yarn add TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8#131/head`

3. Copy the relevant `.node` binary from `/node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/bin` to the `/app/bin` directory.

In my case this was the `sqlserverv8.node.v12.13.0.electron.v7.1.2.x64.node` file. Your webpack output folder may be different, but for me it is the `app` folder since I am using the react boilerplate. You can find your output folder in the webpack config, ensure that it contains a `bin` subfolder with the proper `.node` binary.

4. Use `msnodesqlv8` as usual!